# como dejar un botón activo con css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic

tengo un formulario que creo las filas dinamicamente mediante el botón "add", el cual me genera una fila con un input, textarea y tres botones, mi duda es como puedo dejar los botones presionados (activo) y los otros dos en color gris, me imagino que puede ser capturando algun evento que se gatille, pero en verdad estoy muy perdida, he buscado pero es mi primer proyecto en angular.

formulario.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Formulario Lista" class="bar-positive home">
<ion-content>
    <div class="row header">
       <div class="col"><span>{{codigo}}</span></div>
    <div class="col" style="text-align: right;"><span>{{nombre}}</span></div>
    </div>
    <center>
        <div>
            <img src="https://logo.clearbit.com/codelco.com"/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <form ng-submit="addNew()">
            <div id="dvContenedor">
                <div style="text-align: left;padding-left: 21px;padding-bottom: 10px;"> <input type="submit" class="button button-balanced btn btn-primary pull-right addnew"  value="+ Registro"></div>
                <table id='tblFomrList' class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:95%;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" /></th>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Observación</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
                                    <td style="width: 5%;">
                                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="personalDetail.selected"/></td>
                                    <td style="width: 20%;">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.ID" /></td>
                                    <td style="width: 50%;">
                                       <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.OBS" /> -->
                                        <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.OBS" style="width: 99%;display: inline" rows="4"></textarea></td>
                                    <td style="width: 20%;">
                                       <div ng-model="personalDetail.Status" style="display: flex;">
                                            <input type="button" class="button button-balanced" value="V" ng-click="marcaBoton( $this);"/>
                                            <input type="button" class="button button-energized" value="A" ng-click="marcaBoton( $this);"/>
                                            <input type="button" class="button button-assertive" value="R" ng-click="marcaBoton( $this);"/> 

                                       </div></td>
                                    <td ng-model="personalDetail.Camera" style="width: 5%;"><div><img src="img/cameraAdd.png"/></div></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                            <input ng-hide="!personalDetails.length" type="button" class="button button-assertive btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="remove()" value="Eliminar">
                            <button class="button button-positive">Ingresar</button>
                        </div>

                    <div style="padding-top: 10px;">

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    </center>
</ion-content>
```

formulario.js

```
angular.module("app.controllers")
.controller("FormlarioListaController",function($scope){
   $scope.codigo = "TEST-0001"
   $scope.nombre = "Nombre Componente"
   $scope.personalDetails = [];

   $scope.addNew = function(personalDetail){
       $scope.personalDetails.push({ 
            'ID': "", 
            'OBS': "",
            'Status': "",
            'Camera': ""
        });

        console.log("add new "+$scope.personalDetail);
    };

    $scope.marcaBoton = function($event){
        //debugger;
        console.log("marca boton " + $event);
    };


    $scope.remove = function(){
        var newDataList=[];
        $scope.selectedAll = false;
        angular.forEach($scope.personalDetails, function(selected){
            if(!selected.selected){
                newDataList.push(selected);
            }
        }); 
        $scope.personalDetails = newDataList;
    };

$scope.checkAll = function () {
    if (!$scope.selectedAll) {
        $scope.selectedAll = true;
    } else {
        $scope.selectedAll = false;
    }
    angular.forEach($scope.personalDetails, function(personalDetail) {
        personalDetail.selected = $scope.selectedAll;
    });
}; 
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puramente con CSS no lo podés hacer, pero si con un poco de JS, con eso te podría ayudar...

Comment: claro, igual creo pero no se como hacerlo :c

Comment: Tenes el html y css de tu código, así puedo darte un ejemplo con tu form :P

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con los botones presionados/activos?

Comment: ¿Por qué las etiquetas angularjs e ionic si no los mencionas en la pregunta?

Comment: Otra cosa, la publicación cuenta con dos preguntas, cada una debería hacerse por separado.

Comment: @Rubén he seguido tu consejo y he acotado la pregunta a una sola, he modificado el código ya que ahora si ocupo angular para la creación de las filas. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre que podrías usar [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) de la siguiente forma:

- Al agregar un `Personal`, este debería tener un `Status` por defecto.
- Si el `Status` es igual al valor del `input`, entonces agregas la clase.
  Por ejemplo, si `Status` es igual a  `V`, entonces agregas la clase `button-balanced`.

Entonces el código podría ser algo así:

```js
angular
  .module("ejemplo", [])
  .controller("FormlarioListaController", function($scope) {
    $scope.codigo = "TEST-0001"
    $scope.nombre = "Nombre Componente"
    $scope.personalDetails = [];

    $scope.addNew = function(personalDetail) {
      $scope.personalDetails.push({
        'ID': "",
        'OBS': "",
        'Status': "V",
        'Camera': ""
      });

      console.log("add new " + $scope.personalDetail);
    };

    $scope.marcaBoton = function($event) {
      //debugger;
      console.log("marca boton " + $event);
    };


    $scope.remove = function() {
      var newDataList = [];
      $scope.selectedAll = false;
      angular.forEach($scope.personalDetails, function(selected) {
        if (!selected.selected) {
          newDataList.push(selected);
        }
      });
      $scope.personalDetails = newDataList;
    };

    $scope.checkAll = function() {
      if (!$scope.selectedAll) {
        $scope.selectedAll = true;
      } else {
        $scope.selectedAll = false;
      }
      angular.forEach($scope.personalDetails, function(personalDetail) {
        personalDetail.selected = $scope.selectedAll;
      });
    };
  });
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.3/css/ionic.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ejemplo">
  <div ng-controller="FormlarioListaController">
    <table id='tblFomrList' class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:95%;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" /></th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Observación</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
          <td style="width: 5%;">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="personalDetail.selected" /></td>
          <td style="width: 20%;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.ID" /></td>
          <td style="width: 50%;">
            <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.OBS" /> -->
            <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.OBS" style="width: 99%;display: inline" rows="4"></textarea></td>
          <td style="width: 20%;">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <input type="button" class="button" value="V" ng-click="personalDetail.Status = 'V'" ng-class="{'button-balanced': personalDetail.Status == 'V'}" />
              <input type="button" class="button" value="A" ng-click="personalDetail.Status = 'A'" ng-class="{'button-energized': personalDetail.Status == 'A'}" />
              <input type="button" class="button" value="R" ng-click="personalDetail.Status = 'R'" ng-class="{'button-assertive': personalDetail.Status == 'R'}" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td ng-model="personalDetail.Camera" style="width: 5%;">
            <div><img src="img/cameraAdd.png" /></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 10px;">
      <input ng-hide="!personalDetails.length" type="button" class="button button-assertive btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="remove()" value="Eliminar">
      <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="addNew()">Ingresar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: esta muy bien, ahora el único problema es que me los botones no seleccionados, están en azul

Answer (score 0):

yo optaria por tener un input hidden con valor 0/1 y que al pulsar pusiera el opuesto y segun el tipo pusieras le cambiaras la clase al botón.

1 = clase normal
0 = clase parecida al hover o active

Comment: no entendi lo que pusiste :c igualmente actualice el código, alomejor ahora es mas entendible

Answer (score 0):

## Primera parte

En CSS se define la presentación de los elementos del DOM. La pseudo-clase `:active` se aplica cuando el usuario realiza una acción. Si el usuario no va a realizar la acción, lo que requires es aplicar la misma presentación a los elementos en cuestión.

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, una de ellas es asignando el estilo de la pseudo-clase activo a una clase. El ejemplo siguiente es muy simple, el botón tiene la clase "activo", la cual tiene fondo verde y letra blanca.

```css
.activo {
  color:white;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="V" class="activo">
```

## Segunda parte

Para obtener los ids de los botones, puedes usar alguno de los selectores de elementos del DOM como getElementsByTagName, getElementsByClassName, querySelectAll, entre otros y luego usas `.id`

Los que he mencionado te devuelven una colección, así que deberás usar algún iterador para obtener los id de cada uno.

Ejemplo

En este ejemplo se incluyen tres botones, se querySelectorAll para seleccionar todos los input de tipo botón y se usa for..of para escribir en la consola los id's de cada uno.

```js
var botones = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');
for(var boton of botones){
  console.log(boton.id);
}
```

```html
<input id="uno" type="button" value="Botón 1"/>
<input id="dos" type="button" value="Botón 2"/>
<input id="tres" type="button" value="Botón 3"/>
```

Comment: Estás contestando sólo la mitad de la pregunta, en realidad lo que quiere ella es obtener los botones presionados, seguramente necesite hacerlo usando Javascript.

Comment: @Bitito: Por un lado, las respuestas parciales son válidas, por otro lado, lo que indicas que sobre "lo que en realidad" quiere elsa, no está dicho en la pregunta. Si tienes razón, elsa debería editar la pregunta.

Comment: Si es así, tenés razón, no sabía lo de la respuestas parciales. Si, defitivamente debería cambiar la pregunta!

Comment: @Bitito he modificado la pregunta, algo mas acotada, ademas le agregue el código de angular como se menciona en la etiqueta